# Not receiving BLE notifications when using API 33 for Android 12 device

Tags: android, notifications, bluetooth-lowenergy

The new version of Bluetooth APIs will prevent older versions device (such as Android 12 devices) from receiving notifications, but the old APIs can work normally.

```
public void onCharacteristicChanged (BluetoothGatt gatt, 
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, 
            byte[] value) {
        }
```

API 33, works fine on Android 13, doesn't work on Android 12.

```
        override fun onCharacteristicChanged(gatt: BluetoothGatt,
            characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic
        ) {
        }
```

older version, works fine on Android 13 and 12.

Is there a way to use the new version API but make the devices work normally below Android 12?

Comment: No, there is no way.

Comment: You actually solved a big problem for me. I wasn't receiving BLE notifications on Android 12 but Android 13 was working just fine. Then I realized I was overriding the API 33 onCharacteristicChanged() callback. I'm really surprised the app compiled since my minSdk is 31. I switched to the callback without the byte array parameter and everything is much happier. So thank you for posting this question!

Comment: @GregMoens Thank you so much. I was also running into a dead end with this issue and that worked. It's really annoying that Google is frequently changing APIs and not documenting these things properly.